# QGIS becomes unresponsive when adding new vector layers?

Tags: qgis, vector, windows-10

QGIS suddenly won't allow addition of new vector layers when running on PC (Lyon 2.12.1).  I've reinstalled it, no help.  I've recently changed to Windows 10 from 7, otherwise nothing much has changed on my system.

The program starts up ok, and I can open existing projects and raster files.  When I try to load a new vector file however the program immediately freezes whether using the menu or layers toolbar (before I am asked to choose a layer) and I have to use task manager to close the program.

Any ideas?

I installed an earlier (2.8) version of Qgis but this didn't fix the problem.  I also did a complete uninstall (both versions), then reinstalled the newest version 2.12.3 - no improvement.

I can work with shapefiles within an existing project, but as soon as I try to add a new vector file the program freezes.  Meanwhile version 2.12 works happily on both Mac and another (slower) PC.

Comment: Tell us something about the layer you're trying to add.

Comment: I've had the same problem with layers that have a lot of data, both vector and raster, when using within QGIS without a database. For large data sets, I've used either SQLite or PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hi Daniel, assuming you have two account, goto [Help Center > Contact](http://gis.stackexchange.com/contact) select "I need to merge user profiles" .

Comment: What file type / database system are the vector layers in question? How big are they? Did you try to disable plugins and configuration temporarily?

Comment: Please use the instructions for [merging your two accounts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).  By doing that you will enjoy a much better user experience, and prevent volunteers from having to spend time reviewing your edits.